# Проблема с сохранением списка в объекте

Tags: java, android, arraylist, объекты

Есть библиотека для хранения `key-value` , [Hawk](https://github.com/orhanobut/hawk).

Если у меня есть например: `List<Animal> animals`, который заполнен элементами:

```
animals.add(new Horse());
animals.add(new Cat());
animals.add(new Dog());
```

Я сохраняю ее в `Hawk`, а когда беру обратно, то 
все животные сохранены нужного типа,
но если у меня будет объект `Box`, содержащий `List<Animal> animals`
и я его сохраню, то у меня будет список из `Animal`, которые я не могу преобразовать в `Horse` и т.д..

Comment: Покажите больше кода. Пока что проблема не ясна, а она, скорее всего в классе Box

Comment: Класс Box - просто контейнер. Там только поле List<Animal>

Comment: сохрани в списке кортеж в котором будет исходный объект и его класс.   По этой записи можно будет закастить к исходному типу

Comment: А если проверять на instanceof в цикле каждый из List<Animals>? На каждый из трех классов(Horse, Cat, Dog)?

Comment: instanceof довольно долгий и использовать его стоит только в отладочных целях.

Answer (score 1):

В итоге я отказался от Hawk, попробовал другой инструмент - Paper, там все заработало. Все-таки лучше некоторые вещи писать руками